# meteorjs typeError: Accounts.createUser is not a function

Tags: node.js, meteor

Im having an error when I try to manually create a user on my meteorjs+angular app.

Here is my server code:

```
Meteor.methods({
    createNewUser: function(userInfo){
        Accounts.createUser(userInfo);
    }
});
```

Im calling that using angular-meteor in this way:

```
$scope.save = function(){
    $meteor.call('createNewUser', $scope.account);
}
```

And the error goes like this:

> Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'createNewUser'
>   TypeError: Accounts.createUser is not a function....

My `.meteor/packages` file:

```
meteor-platform
twbs:bootstrap
pfafman:font-awesome-4
urigo:angular
angularui:angular-ui-router
aldeed:collection2
underscore
accounts-password
```

Comment: $scope.account Check if the type is a function or a dictionary

Comment: Are you sure `accounts-base` is added?

Comment: accounts-base is added automatically as a dependency to accounts-password.

Comment: @user1787687 The error is not related to `$scope.account` being a function or a dictionary.